# c++ std::array warning

Tags: c++, arrays, stl

On the following code

```
std::array<int,3> myarray = {10,20,30};
```

I am receiving the following compiler warning

```
warning: missing braces around initializer for ‘std::array<int, 3u>::value_type [3] {aka int [3]}’ [-Wmissing-braces]
```

Why ?

toolchain: (edit)

```
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Should we *guess* what toolchain you're using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

`std::array<int,3> = {{10, 20, 30}}`

I think this was a bug they fixed in versions > 4.6

Answer (score 6):

As Tyler indicated, `std::array` is a POD, so it has no constructors, and it contains an array. To initialise it with brace syntax, you initialise the variable, and then the array inside the variable, with the nested braces.

```
{ { 10, 20, 30 } }
  ^ For the array member variable inside the std::array object
^ For the std::array object
```

Actually this is a bug in your compiler, because aggregate initialisation allows you to remove a layer of braces after an `=`. So these two are legal:

```
std::array<int,3> x = {10, 20, 30};
std::array<int,3> y  {{10, 20, 30}};
```

But not

```
std::array<int,3> z {10, 20, 30};
```

The last one compiles on GCC but it's a nonstandard extension and you should get a warning.

Comment: Works with only a single pair of braces on g++ 4.7, though.

Comment: Works single-bracket as well on my mac, LLVM 4.2. Thus the reason I asked what chain he had.

Comment: @WhozCraig apparently aggregate initialisation allows you to remove a layer after an `=`.

Comment: @SethCarnegie yeah, I see that now. Interesting how you're need to be container-aware without it. At least you can still do it though, which is more than many of things in older implementations.

Comment: @Seth "But not `std::array<int,3> z {10, 20, 30};` " <- that  works on g++ 4.7.

Comment: @us2012 you get a warning about missing braces. It's nonstandard. Clang doesn't allow it.

Comment: @Seth you're right :) I forgot the `-Wall` when I tried. I also get the warning for your 'legal' single-brace `=` assignment though.

Comment: @SethCarnegie `std::array<int,3> z {10, 20, 30};` does NOT work on Apple LLVM 4.2. (which is just clang, in case anyone cared). The error is very descriptive: *"Cannot omit braces around initialization of subobject when using direct list-initialization"*, and the fix-proposal is enlightening : `std::array<int,3> z {{10,20,30}};`. Ha!

Comment: @SethCarnegie Laptop, can only cut/paste so fast flipping from one virt-desk to another and back =P